# Can a Windows 7 DVD be used to install both 32-bit and 64-bit versions?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation, dvd, 32-bit

I have a Windows 7 Professional DVD, but it doesn't specify whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit.

If it was a 32-bit DVD, can I use it to also install Windows on a 64-bit system, or do I need to get another copy of Windows which is 64-bit enabled?

Comment: does the DVD say anything about x86, x64, ia64, etc? What *does* it say on it?

Comment: okies, got it its x64..I guess that is 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are on separate DVD images.

Comment: incorrect. There are tons of all-in-one 32-64-bit install images for Windows. For example [3 Ways To Create An x86 and x64 All in one Windows 7 ISO](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/create-x86-x64-all-one-windows-7-iso/)

Comment: I can't delete this accepted answer... I think it might have been true six years ago, but I have no idea now.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to delete a file in the image and it will unlock all the versions with 32 and 64 bit selections.

> ***Prerequisite***
>
> 1. Windows 7 DVD or Image File (iso)
> 2. Image Editor Tool
> 3. Image Burning Tool
> 4. Basic Computer Knowledge
>
> *Note:*
>
> - It doesn't matter which ever version of Windows 7 you have got
> - It also doesn't matter which platform you have got i.e. x64 or x86
> - You can use image editor softwares such as [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/), [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/), [UltraISO](http://ultraiso.en.softonic.com/) etc.
> - For Image Writing Tool, I usually prefer [Nero](http://www.nero.com/enu/)
> - You should know how to mount, save, edit the image file using the above tools
> - Make a copy of your Image file or DVD incase you mess up things
>
> ***Instructions for DVD***
>
> 1. Open Image Editing software and select your DVD Drive
> 2. Select Save As option from the File menu and save it to .iso format
> 3. Browse to the "sources" folder
> 4. Find a file named "ei.cfg" and delete it
> 5. Save the Image file
> 6. Burn the Image using Nero or any other Image Writing software
>
> ***Instructions for Image File***
>
> 1. Open Image File with Image Editing software
> 2. Browse to the "sources" folder
> 3. Find a file named "ei.cfg" and delete it
> 4. Save the Image file
> 5. Burn the Image using Nero or any other Image Writing software
>
> Next time you boot with the DVD, you will get a screen wherein you can
>   choose between different versions of windows like Ultimate,
>   Professional, Home Basic etc.

[Source](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/26885-Unlock-all-versions-of-Windows-7-from-your-DVD-or-Image-file-%28x64-or-x86%29)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please include information from the link instead of just posting the link itself.

Comment: I would like to point out that this is not a direct answer to what the poster is asking, but still relates to closely.

Comment: These steps worked but didn't help me out unfortunately. With my WIndows 7 Ultimate Disc it gave me options for starter, home, professional ect but all options were x86 and not 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon: Windows 7 Home Premium](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DHGMK0)
[Amazon: Windows 7 Professional](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DHLVII)

Both say "(includes 32 & 64-bit versions)".

Don't know if other answer is old editions, but those two copies seem to have both on one DVD. Which is my understanding of what comes on the DVD.

I also have a DVD for my work computer which specifies 32bit. Since it's a 32bit computer, they may have built a copy just for it (Dell included DVD).

Moral of the story: It probably depends on your DVD. I'm fairly certain that customer DVD's include both versions.

Comment: The retail versions of Windows 7 come with *two separate DVDs* each with their own architecture on it. One for x86, one for x64.

Comment: Ahh... I've yet to mess with a retail box. My copies have been either corporate or educational.